# CakePHP form not working

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have created a Controller, a model and a view for this. I want to make a form in CakePHP. But this is not working and till now I cannot understand the reason why is this happening...

My code for the controller is:

```
class MlistsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');

    public function create() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Mlist->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('okay..'));
                $this->redirect('action' => 'index');
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

My Model is:

```
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class MList extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public $validate = array(
        'listname' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A listname '
            )
        ),
        'replyto' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'email' => 'email'
            )
        ),
        'fromName' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your name'
            )
        ),
        'subject' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A subject '
            )
        ),
        'reminder' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A reminder '
            )
        ),
        'contactsfile' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'custom message'
            )
        ));

}
```

And my view file create.ctp is:

```
<h2>Create new list</h2>

<?php
    $this->Form->create('Mlist');
    echo $this->Form->input('listname',array('label' => 'Your ListName:'));;
    echo $this->Form->input('replyto',array('label' => 'Reply To email:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('fromName',array('label' => 'From Name:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('subject',array('label' => 'mail subject:'));
    echo $this->Form->input('reminder',array('label' => 'Reminder'));
    echo $this->Form->input('contactsfile',array('label' => 'Upload your file','type' => 'file'));
    echo '<br />';
    echo $this->Form->end('submit');
```

Finally, the Submit button of the form is not even green, but grey and does not function when I click it. Also the star symbol (*) is not showing apart the form labels where the fields are required...

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: It won't add asterisk automatically. You have to style accordingly.

Comment: i use the default cakephp layout,which does this automatically. In other forms i've created on the same CakePHP installation,it works correctly..

Comment: Your model-name starts with *two* capitals in stead of one (it should be `Mlist`. Furthermore, since you've got no code at all inside your controller, It will not save anything

Comment: i added some code:if($this->request->is('post')) {
   if($this->Mlist->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('okay..'));
    $this->redirect('action' => 'index');
   }
  } in my controller and changed the two capital letters in the Model,but nothing works either now..:/

Comment: Did you rename the file of your Model as well? Also, what is the name of the database-table used for the Mlist model?

Comment: yes,i renamed the file of my Model as well...the table used for this is called 'mlists'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're kind of bypassing Cake's ['Convention over configuration'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) paradigm.
In order for these conventions to work Cake uses the [Inflector Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) which handles the **plural forms of English words**.

So when you use an appropriate (to this convention) naming policy it will work for you "out of the box". Otherwise you will have to configure the [Model](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html), [Controller](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Controller.html) and any [Helpers](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Helper.html)/[Components](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Component.html)/Behaviours you're using. They all have configuration parameters for this, but there is not a big point in doing this static configuration with Cake since you will also have to go through it again if you rename a DB table for example.
I's just against the idea of Cake. If you need to do this just use some other configuration based framework.

Comment: Do you mean that i have to use as my model name 'Mlists' and not 'Mlist' ?? Cause i do not see anywhere else non-plural names :/

Comment: Well no. Use **real words or word combinations**. Read the conventions link I provided carefully a couple of times. `Mlists` is not a plural form of any word since `mlist` is not a word.

Comment: Ok,i'll try to use something else and update this issue here ih i still have errors nagging me :/

Comment: the problem still persists :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your view. You also have to echo the starting of the form:

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Mlist');
```

The naming convention is ok. Cake doesn't have any database of real english words, only few irregularities (see arrays in http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Inflector.html) so anything like Mlist is just pluralized with adding "s" at the end.